# How to get the closest datetime object in a list?

Tags: python, list, datetime, if-statement, lambda

I have a list, `matched_rows_2` which looks like this:

```
matched_rows_2 = 
[['1','01-01-2021','10:18:00','100','TTF'],
 ['2','01-01-2021','10:18:00','100','GGY'],
 ['3','01-01-2021','10:22:00','120','HHJ'],
 ['4','01-01-2021','10:23:00','160','JJH'],
 ['5','01-01-2021','10:26:14','160','RRT'],
 ['6','01-01-2021','10:27:59','160','PPO'],
 ['7','01-01-2021','10:29:58','100','KKG'],
 ['8', '01-01-2021','10:30:50','160','PPO']]
```

Now for every `x` inside above `list` Im trying to get the `x` which has a `datetime` that is the closest to `chosen_datetime`.

This is my code:

```
chosen_datetime = 2021-01-01 10:16:00+00:00 #<--- this is a datetime aware time object.

timezone = "Europe/London"
chosen_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(chose_datetime).astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone))
timeDiff = chosen_datetime.utcoffset().total_seconds()
chosen_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(chosen_datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeDiff)


matched_rows_3 = []
for x in matched_rows_2:
    start_traject_time = x[1] + ' ' + x[2]
    start_traject_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_traject_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    start_traject_time = pytz.utc.localize(start_traject_time)
    if min(start_traject_time, key=lambda d: abs(d -  chosen_datetime)):
        matched_rows_3.append(x)
```

**This the my current output:**

```
    if min(start_traject_time, key=lambda d: abs(d - chosen_datetime)):
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
1   01-01-2021  10:18:00    100 TTF 
2   01-01-2021  10:18:00    100 GGY 
3   01-01-2021  10:22:00    120 HHJ 
4   01-01-2021  10:23:00    160 JJH
```

Please note that my `datetime` objects are all `datetime awar`e objects, I want to keep it like that.

Comment: basically, the first argument to `min` should be a list of all the datetime objects you want to compare to `chosen_datetime`

Comment: @MrFuppes what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

the first argument to [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) must be an iterable, e.g. a list with all the datetime objects you want to compare to your `chosen_datetime`. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

matched_rows_2 = [
        ['1','01-01-2021','10:18:00','100','TTF'],
        ['2','01-01-2021','10:18:00','100','GGY'],
        ['3','01-01-2021','10:22:00','120','HHJ'],
        ['4','01-01-2021','10:23:00','160','JJH'],
        ['5','01-01-2021','10:26:14','160','RRT'],
        ['6','01-01-2021','10:27:59','160','PPO'],
        ['7','01-01-2021','10:29:58','100','KKG'],
        ['8','01-01-2021','10:30:50','160','PPO']
        ]

# first extract date & time and parse to datetime object. optionally set tzinfo to UTC
dts = []
for row in matched_rows_2:
    dts.append(datetime.strptime(row[1]+row[2], "%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc))
 
# dts 
# [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 22, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 26, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 27, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 29, 58, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 30, 50, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]
```

Now that you have all the datetime objects in a list, you can use `min` to get the value with minimum difference to your chosen_date:

```
chosen_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-01-01 10:23:00+00:00")

# now to get the element in l + the index
min_val = min(dts, key=lambda d: abs(d - chosen_datetime))
min_idx = dts.index(min_val)

# or in one line (more efficient but less readable)
min_idx, min_val = min(zip(range(len(dts)), dts), key=lambda d: abs(d[1] - chosen_datetime))

print(min_val, min_idx, matched_rows_2[min_idx])
# 2021-01-01 10:23:00+00:00 3 ['4', '01-01-2021', '10:23:00', '160', 'JJH']

print(matched_rows_2[:min_idx+1])
# [['1', '01-01-2021', '10:18:00', '100', 'TTF'], 
#  ['2', '01-01-2021', '10:18:00', '100', 'GGY'], 
#  ['3', '01-01-2021', '10:22:00', '120', 'HHJ'], 
#  ['4', '01-01-2021', '10:23:00', '160', 'JJH']]
```

Comment: but how do I make `start_traject_time` a list? As I cant use that range function because that range is everytime different.

Comment: @TangerCity wait, I'll add that to the example as well ;-)

Comment: Okay, but you dont have the same output as me...how comes you only find the `10:23:00` as output?

Comment: @TangerCity: I've revised the example. Do you mean you want all elements up to a certain datetime?

Comment: let me try your example. No not to a certain datetime. Just closest to `chosen_time`

Comment: not its still not giving the correct output. Your output is different then mine still.Where is the row with 160 in your output?

Comment: @TangerCity: that's just a matter of the slicing; use `l[:min_idx+1]` if you want to *include* the min element.

Comment: I edited my input data `matched_rows_2` so that you can use it to. Can you try and do it inside the for loop I wrote and show me how its done?

Comment: @TangerCity: yup, done. The point is that you don't call `min` inside the loop, you only use a loop to get all the datetimes in an iterable. *Then* you can use the `min` function with that iterable as input.

Comment: works great on this dataset yes. However, I tried it on a different dataset but got un-satisfied results.